# My data transfer queue is giving wrong values

Tags: arrays, c, struct, queue

This is my queue Header

```
#include"limits.h"
#include"stdio.h"
#include"pthread.h"
#include"unistd.h"
#include"stdlib.h"
#include"string.h"
#include"time.h"
pthread_mutex_t lock;


typedef struct{
    int* message;
    void*in_array;
}data_pack;

 data_pack* createpack()
{

     data_pack* pack = malloc(sizeof( data_pack));
     return pack;
}

// Queue Structure
struct Queue {
    int front, rear, size; // front, rare and the size of the Queue
    unsigned long long capacity; // stores the capacity of the Queue
    data_pack** array; //2D array to store the array of arrays
    int* array_sizes; //1D array to store the number of elements of each array
    data_pack** remArray; //2D array to store the remaining array of arrays(used for flush)
};


// Creates a Queue
struct Queue* createQueue()
{
    struct Queue* queue = (struct Queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));
    queue->front = queue->size = 0;
    queue->capacity = queue->size + 1;
    queue->rear = queue->capacity - 1;
    queue->array = (data_pack **)malloc(queue->capacity * sizeof(data_pack));// changed to my struct
    queue->array_sizes = (int *)malloc(queue->capacity * sizeof(int));



    if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0) {
            printf("\n mutex init has failed\n");
            return 0;
        }
    return queue;
}

// Queue is empty when size is 0
int isEmpty(struct Queue* queue)
{

    return (queue->size == 0);

}

// Function to add an array to the queue.
// It changes rear and size
void enqueue(struct Queue* queue, data_pack arr[], int n)
{
    int i=0;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);// lock variables
    queue->rear = (queue->rear + 1) % queue->capacity;
    queue->array[queue->rear] = (data_pack *)malloc(n*sizeof(data_pack));
    if(queue->array[queue->rear]==NULL) printf("Error in memory\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        queue->array[queue->rear][i] = arr[i];// u need to input struct here

    }
    queue->array_sizes[queue->rear] = n;
    queue->size = queue->size + 1;
    queue->capacity = queue->capacity + 1;
    queue->array = (data_pack**)realloc(queue->array,queue->capacity*sizeof(data_pack));
    if(queue->array == NULL) printf("Not 2d array");
    queue->array_sizes = (int*)realloc(queue->array_sizes,queue->capacity*sizeof(int));
    if(queue->array_sizes == NULL) printf("not 1dn array sizes");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);// unlock variables

}

// Function to remove an array from queue.
// It changes front and size
data_pack* dequeue(struct Queue* queue)
{
    int i=0;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);// lock variables
    int len = queue->array_sizes[queue->front];
    data_pack* deqArray = (data_pack*)malloc(len*sizeof(data_pack));
    if (isEmpty(queue))
        return 0;

    for( i=0;i<queue->array_sizes[queue->front];i++){

        deqArray[i] = queue->array[queue->front][i];
    }


    queue->front = (queue->front + 1) % queue->capacity;
    queue->size = queue->size - 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);// unlock variables
    free(queue->array[queue->front-1]);

    return deqArray;
}

// Function to flush all the arrays and its elements from the queue.
data_pack** flush(struct Queue* queue)
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    queue->remArray = (data_pack **)malloc(queue->size * sizeof(data_pack));
    int k=0;
    for( i=queue->front;i<=queue->rear;i++){
        int len = queue->array_sizes[i];
        queue->remArray[k] = (data_pack *)malloc(len*sizeof(data_pack));
        for( j=0;j<len;j++){

            //queue->remArray[k][j] = queue->array[i][j];
        }
        free(queue->array[i]);

        k++;
    }
    free(queue->array);
    free(queue->array_sizes);
    queue->front = queue->size = 0;
    queue->capacity = queue->size + 1;
    queue->rear = queue->capacity - 1;
    queue->array_sizes = (int *)malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
    queue->array = (data_pack **)malloc(1 * sizeof(data_pack));
    return queue->remArray;
}

// Function to know number of arrays in queue
int no_elements(struct Queue* queue)
{

    return queue->size;


}
```

my running code is this

```
struct Queue * send_data_queue;
data_pack data_to_send;
data_pack * rec_data;
typedef struct SenderData {
  unsigned short CommandCode;
  int DataSize;
  void * Data;
}
SenderData;

int cont[200];

SenderData data, dat;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

  send_data_queue = createQueue();

  while (1) {
    data.DataSize = sizeof(cont);
    data.Data = & cont;
    data.CommandCode = 20;

    data_to_send[0].message = 20;
    data_to_send[0].in_array = & data;

    enqueue(send_data_queue, &data_to_send, 1);

    int nos = no_elements(send_data_queue);
    printf("No of elements in q = %d\n", nos); // this is printing correctly

    rec_data = dequeue(send_data_queue);

    dat = *(SenderData *)rec_data->in_array;
    printf("size is %d\n",dat.DataSize);

  }

  return 0;
}
```

Explaining my code

-I'm trying to enqueue an array which is int array of 200 Elements

I'm updating my struct data with required info such as size, command and the actual data

This queue utilizes a struct to pass data, so i update my struct data to this struct

Then i call enqueue function

then i check the queue size, its updating correctly

I'm trying to dequeue data

here I'm casting the data to struct which is Sender data

but when i print, I'm getting results as this

```
size is 0
No of elements inq = 1
size is 0
No of elements inq = 1
size is 0
No of elements inq = 1
size is 0
No of elements inq = 1
size is 0
No of elements inq = 1
size is 0
No of elements inq = 1
size is 0
No of elements inq = 1
size is 0
No of elements inq = 1
```

but actual expected is

```
size is 800 
No of elements inq = 1
```

Comment: The explanation is exactly the same as your prior question.  Update it to describe your **current** problem, along with the expected output and a copy/paste of the actual output

Comment: Your explanation sounds as if yor program were compiled correcty, but faced a run-time issue. Yet, "Invalid Use of Void Expression" suggests a compiler error. If so, please include the exact message.

Comment: @M Oehm now program is ruining, it was my mistake, i have updated my question